# Text changed signal for Text View widget in GTK3

Tags: python, gtk3

How can I find out when the text has been changed in a text view widget in the GTK3 framework? I think there must be a signal associated with it, but could not find it.
For example, there is an ontextchanged signal in qt4, so there should be a similar signal in GTK. I am using Python.

Comment: The answer is correct (I have just checked), could you please accept it so it is ranked higher in the search results?

Answer (score 11):

Every `TextView` widget is associated to a `TextBuffer` object. The signal you are looking for is `changed` but of the associated text buffer. If you create a `TextView` without an associated buffer, a default one is created for you and you can retrieve it with `textview.get_buffer()`